# Using <xsl:apply-templates> and <xsl:sort>

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I use the  element to sort the  elements within the table I am outputting? I would like to use the  elements within the  element. I tried placing the  element in my xsl document but it doesn't sort the  element.

Here is my xml:

```
<presidents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="president.xsd" date="2014-09-24" >
    <president>
        <number>1</number>
        <name>George Washington</name>
         <birthday>1732-02-22</birthday>
        <took_office>1789-04-30</took_office>
        <left_office>1797-03-04</left_office>
        <party>no party</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>1</term_number>
            <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president> 
        </term>
        <term>
            <term_number>2</term_number>
            <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>

    <president>
        <number>2</number>
        <name>John Adams</name>
         <birthday>1735-10-30</birthday>
        <took_office>1797-03-04</took_office>
        <left_office>1801-03-04</left_office>
        <party>Federalist</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>3</term_number>
            <vice_president>Thomas Jefferson</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>
</presidents>
```

And here is my .xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_table.css"/>
    <title>Table of Us Presidents</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Table of Us Presidents</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>Took Office</th>
                <th>Left Office</th>
                <th>Party</th>
                <th>Vice President</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="president">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="birthday"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="took_office"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="left_office"/></td>
    <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="party">
        <xsl:sort select="party"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="term">
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
        <xsl:value-of select="vice_president" /><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is never more than one `party` element inside a `president` element. Why would it need sorting? Would you like to sort something else?

Comment: Ok sorry I guess I didn't describe my problem well. I would like to output the data so it is sorted according to the <party> element in an alphabetical order. So all of the 'Democratic' presidents would appear first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to output the data so it is sorted according to the  element in an alphabetical order. So all of the 'Democratic' presidents would appear first.

Then, let us test with an example where the natural order of elements would *not* suggest that a Democratic president comes first in the output:

**XML Input**

```
<presidents date="2014-09-24" >
    <president>
        <number>1</number>
        <name>George Washington</name>
         <birthday>1732-02-22</birthday>
        <took_office>1789-04-30</took_office>
        <left_office>1797-03-04</left_office>
        <party>Federalist</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>1</term_number>
            <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president> 
        </term>
        <term>
            <term_number>2</term_number>
            <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>

    <president>
        <number>2</number>
        <name>John Adams</name>
         <birthday>1735-10-30</birthday>
        <took_office>1797-03-04</took_office>
        <left_office>1801-03-04</left_office>
        <party>Democratic</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>3</term_number>
            <vice_president>Thomas Jefferson</vice_president>
        </term>
    </president>
</presidents>
```

Then, on to sorting your data. Currently, you are applying `xsl:sort` in the context of a template matching `president`, like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="party">
  <xsl:sort select="party"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

But the unit you'd like to sort is not `party`, but `president` elements. It just that the sort *condition* is the textual content of the `party` element, which is a child element of `president`.

So, you have to apply sorting higher up in the XML hierarchy for the desired effect. You have to sort in the context of `presidents`, where templates are applied to `president` elements.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" indent="yes" /> 

    <xsl:template match="/presidents">
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_table.css"/>
    <title>Table of Us Presidents</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Table of Us Presidents</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>Took Office</th>
                <th>Left Office</th>
                <th>Party</th>
                <th>Vice President</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="president">
                <xsl:sort select="party"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="president">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="birthday"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="took_office"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="left_office"/></td>
    <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="party"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="term">
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
        <xsl:value-of select="vice_president" /><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**HTML Output**

As you can see, the president with the Democratic party now comes first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_table.css">
      <title>Table of Us Presidents</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Table of Us Presidents</h1>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Took Office</th>
            <th>Left Office</th>
            <th>Party</th>
            <th>Vice President</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>John Adams</td>
            <td>1735-10-30</td>
            <td>1797-03-04</td>
            <td>1801-03-04</td>
            <td>Democratic</td>
            <td>1. Thomas Jefferson<br></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>George Washington</td>
            <td>1732-02-22</td>
            <td>1789-04-30</td>
            <td>1797-03-04</td>
            <td>Federalist</td>
            <td>1. John Adams<br>2. John Adams<br></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that initially and what ends up happening is only the table headers show up and the rest of the data disappears. I am previewing the xml file in firefox.

Comment: ok figured it out and I don't know why it works with this solution. I changed:
<xsl:apply-templates select="president">
   <xsl:sort select="party"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
to:
<xsl:apply-templates select="//president">
   <xsl:sort select="party"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

Comment: @esgg No, you did not try exactly that initially. I'm willing to bet that your first template matched for `/`, whereas my first template matches for `/presidents`.

Comment: I tried so many variations I was going mad! I'm just glad you helped me figure it out! Thank you :)